# Header named 'Cookie' not always set using Firefox

Tags: javascript, http, jquery, cookies, http-headers

I am using ajax to post to an endpoint within a javascript function.  Before I post, I set a header with the name 'Cookie' on the request.  I have tried setting the header both using beforeSend and using 'headers' (see code below), but the header is only sometimes set. Much of the time the 'Cookie' header is not set.  I can tell this by looking at the header in firebug for a Post request.  I only have this problem with the header named 'Cookie'.  All other headers are consistently set.  I can't change the name of the 'Cookie' header to a different value as it is required for the service that I am calling.

```
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    type:'POST',
    contentType: "application/xml",
    beforeSend: function (request)
        {
            request.setRequestHeader("Cookie", authCookie);
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Authentication id=company.platform.services.org.test,app_secret=aEWEvsddsdddddds0");
        },
    headers: {"Cookie": "abc.etc.authid=" + companyID + ",abc.etc.ticket=" + ticket, "Authorization": "Authentication id=company.platform.services.org.test,app_secret=aEWEvsddsdddddds0"},
    data: order,
    success: createOrderCallback,
    error: createOrderError
});
```

Is there a better way to set this header to ensure that it will always be set for each request?

Comment: You can't set a cookie (for a different domain) using AJAX.

Comment: The "Cookie" header is controlled by the browser. Use `document.cookie` to manipulate the cookie ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to set the cookie header with XHR http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader()-method

The only reason it appeared to work is probably because you had actual cookies the browser sent.

Comment: Well it's impossible to directly set it, but if it's a same-domain URL then changes to `document.cookie` would be reflected, no?

Comment: @Pointy well yes but that is not the same thing exactly. `document.cookie` doesn't have any control over httponly headers for example whereas setting `cookie` header would have all control.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll look into other ways to make this post request and be able to set the 'Cookie' header.  If you have a suggestion for a different way to post to a web service and set the 'Cookie' header, please let me know.